# ASP.NET Core's BindNever does not work with record

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, model-binding, asp.net-core-7.0, c#-record-type

When using Razor Pages 7 I have this in the code-behind file:

```cs
public record PersonDto(
  long Id,
  string Name,
  [BindNever] string Address,
  // ...
);

[BindProperty] public PersonDto Person { get; set; }
```

I populate that in the `OnGet()` and show it on the page. I read it in the `OnPost()` to update the database.

But `Address` is supposed to be read-only. I do not allow it to be changed, so the post handler always fails with a validation error of `"The Address field is required"`.

The `BindNever` attribute does not work on the record (even though [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#constructor-binding-and-record-types) show that it should).

I also tried the long-form record syntax, and the `[property:BindNever]` syntax, with the same result.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. I replaced this:

```cs
[BindNever] string Address,
```

with this:

```cs
[property:BindNever] string? Address,
```

Comment: You probably still want to add the `[BindNever]` attribute to the nullable property to prevent an over-posting attack.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks Mike. Any idea why the attribute alone doesn't suffice? In the model binding [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#constructor-binding-and-record-types) it shows it being used in a record. Also I assume I need to use `[property:BindNever]`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: A non-nullable string is treated as required by the model binder if you enable nullable contexts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute